# Trim or split opus on android without ffmpeg

Tags: java, android, audio, trim, opus

Trim or split opus on android without ffmpeg

The opus file could be contained in any format supported by ffmpeg export
(Created when building the app,ffmpeg too heavy to include in app)

I tried genVideoUsingMuxer , MediaExtractor ,MediaMetadataRetriever but it fails with error

```
Unsupported mime 'audio/opus'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to add the track to the muxerat android.media.MediaMuxer.nativeAddTrack(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaMuxer.addTrack(MediaMuxer.java:660)
```

Any way i can trim the audio on android with a lightweight solution

**Reencoding is not needed but its ok if output format is anything playable on android**

Comment: Is there any chance you forgot to split by ABI? FFmpeg is at most 8 MB. Is this size unacceptable for your need?

Comment: yes, at max 500kb in universal apk is requirement

Comment: I will try creating a demo in my free time. I think you can compile ffmpeg with only required dependencies. Also, did you try the codec from https://opus-codec.org/downloads/?

Comment: I've done quite a lot esearch on this and found out that i can trim ogg without transcoding by just selecting the ogg pages in timeframe and append them to the head. I don't know how to convert opus Granule position  to a timestamp so  I can include or exclude it from trimming  https://github.com/leonfancy/oggus/issues/2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70093101/ogg-opus-granule-position-to-timestamp